# Uniform continuity of function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f:( 0, ∞)→R$ such that 
$f(x) = 1/x $  then we know it is not uniformly continuous. As shown in graph, for any given $ε >0$, the same $δ$ does not work everywhere on graph. That is, $δ$ changes for same $ε$ for the different portion of graph, So that function is not uniformly continuous.[image: graph of $f(x) = 1/x $ in $(0,∞$]

Now, if we consider $g(x) = 1/x $ in $(a, ∞)$ where $a > 0$ then too, I have different $δ$, for same $ε$ in different portion of graph. So why $g(x) = 1/x$ is  uniformly continuous on $(a,∞)$ where $a> 0$?

Comment: Intuitively the problem with $f$ that makes it fail to be uniformly continuous that the slope of $f$ grows arbitrarily large. For any $a > 0$, the derivative of $g$ is bounded and so $g$ is uniformly continuous. See if you can work through the $\epsilon-\delta$ argument and you'll find there indeed is a $\delta$ for every $\epsilon$ which works for the entire interval.

Comment: Please clarify, how I get same $δ$ for $g(x)$ which works for entire interval.

Comment: The $\delta$ is not unique. Choosing a smaller $\delta$ works. Uniform continuity means that we can choose a $\delta$ that works regardless of which points are chosen - dependent only on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we consider the interval $I=(a,\infty)$, then we see that, for any $x,x' \in I$:
\begin{align*}
\lvert f(x) - f(x') \rvert &= \left\lvert \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x'} \right\rvert \\
&= \left\lvert \frac{x'-x}{x\cdot x'} \right\rvert \\
&< \frac{1}{a^2} \cdot \left\lvert x'-x \right\rvert \\
\end{align*}
For any $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose $\delta = a^2\epsilon$ and see that:
$$ \lvert x - x' \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(x') \rvert < \epsilon \qquad \forall x,x' \in I$$
By definition, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $I$.

To answer your question about why concerning the $\delta$ - the $\delta$ is not unique. Choosing a smaller $\delta$ works. Uniform continuity means that we can choose a $\delta$ that works regardless of which points are chosen - dependent only on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. Can we see this $ δ = a^2 ε$ works for entire interval via graph?

Comment: How about imagining this: For any given epsilon, if 'a' is in the interval [0,1), then  the delta would be smaller than epsilon,i.e. the width of the delta-rectangular strip would be smaller than the epsilon-rectangular. If a is a real >=1, then the delta strip would be wider than the epsilon strip so that it can move along and cover all domain points that the epsilon strip covers as it is moved along the curve.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $g : (a,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ given by $g(x) = 1/x$. Take $\delta = a^2\epsilon$. Note that for any $x,y \in (a,\infty)$, $xy \ge a^2$ so $1/(xy) \le 1/a^2$. Then if $|x-y| < \delta$,

$$
\left| \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} \right| = \frac{|y-x|}{xy} \le \frac{|y-x|}{a^2} < \frac{\delta}{a^2} = \epsilon
$$

Comment: Thanks get it. I think it is impossible to see this δ works for entire interval via graph?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi It is: the problem that you had originally is the closer you get to 0, the larger your $\delta$ needs to be. In this case, you have a hard boundary on the left, at $x = a$: the graph is at its steepest there so if you have a $\delta$ that works in that region, it works everywhere. In other words: if you have an $(\delta, \epsilon)$ rectangle that works near $x = a$, you can use the same rectangle everywhere and since the graph is less steep there, it will definitely fit in the same rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it is not uniformly cont on $(a,\infty)$. Then there exist sequence $u_n$ and $v_n$ such that $|u_n-v_n|\to 0$ but $|f(u_n)-f(v_n)|\not\to 0$. However we have $|f(u_n)-f(v_n)| =|1/u_n -1/v_n| =|\dfrac{v_n-u_n}{u_nv_n}|$. As long as $u_nv_n$ doesn't go to zero(because of our interval), we can evaluate the limit of the top and bottom separately. The numerator limits to zero, and the denominator will be bounded by $1/a$ and $0$. Thus $|f(u_n)-f(v_n)|\to 0$. This is a contradiction, thus $f$ is uniformly continuous on the interval.

Intuitively, uniform continuity means that the function cannot get too steep. As slope increases, the ratio of change in y to change in x increase. In epsilon-delta terminology, this means that our function cant have an infinitely large epsilon for a infinitely small delta. In this case the "steep" part of the function happens in the limit towards zero. When we choose the interval to $(0,\infty)$ we lose uniform continuity. But when we cap the interval at $a$, the slope of our function can be bounded, and so it is uniformly continuous.